# Core Data Vs Value Objects

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a data which will remain fresh for 30 minutes
Which way of storing the data is advantageous:
1. Storing it in CORE data and clear it after 30 minutes.
2. Storing it in Value Objects, save it in a Array and clean it after 30 mins or when app goes off.

Comment: This is too vague. Provide more details about the nature of the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData can hold your data in memory or on disk, the real question is will it be easier to get your data in to core data, or in to a value object.

CoreData will also make managing the memory required to store your data easier, but that really only matters if the volume of data is large.